# Adding colormap to add_collection (surface in 3d plot)

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d, color-mapping

I am making a 3 sided pyramid I have made the sides using add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection

But I want to add a colormap based on the z axis so that the top is red and it gradually change to blue but the details does not matter. I tried the cmap option but that does change the color.

I have added a script with one side to illustrate the problem.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

#Pyramid side 1
xp1 = [1.1184,2.46,2.46]
yp1 = [0.5592, 1.23,2.73]
zp1 = [-1.5,0,-1.5]
verts1= [zip(xp1,yp1,zp1)]

cmhot = plt.cm.get_cmap("hot")
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts1,cmap=cmhot))

ax.set_xlim(0,5)
ax.set_ylim(0,5)
ax.set_zlim(-2.5,5)
plt.show()
```

Why does this not work?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You have to convert zip into list format

```
list(zip(xp1,yp1,zp1))
```